# Is "They always hurt her" present or past?

Tags: verb-forms, ambiguity

could someone in that sentence " they always hurt her "...how to know that it's past or present...?
if we assumed that the sentence is in present can be rewritten in passive voice such as   " She always gets hurt = she is always hurt "..and does both sentences write..?
if " they always hurt her " is in past ...so how to rewrite in passive voice..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Because *hurt* doesn't have different forms (except in the third person singular) for past and present, the sentence is ambiguous. You must look to the context to determine whether past or present tense is meant.

   > They always hurt her
   >
   > > Whatever she **does**<sup>present</sup> to pacify them, they always **hurt**<sup>present</sup> her.
   > >     Whatever she   **did**<sup>past</sup>   to pacify them, they always **hurt**<sup>past</sup>    her.
2. To express a past-tense passive you employ the past form of the auxiliary.

   > Whatever she **does**<sup>present</sup> to pacify them, she   **is**<sup>present</sup> always  hurt.
   >   Whatever she **does**<sup>present</sup> to pacify them, she always **gets**<sup>present</sup>  hurt.
   >
   > Whatever she **did**<sup>past</sup> to pacify them, she **was**<sup>past</sup> always  hurt.
   >   Whatever she **did**<sup>past</sup> to pacify them, she always  **got**<sup>past</sup> hurt.

Comment: um very grateful dude... u have done ur best..

Answer (score 1):

the word "always" show a habit here "of getting hurt", so the tense here is apparently present simple, and the passive voice is "she is always her" as you mentioned, but if we remove "always" the sentence become "they hurt her", then there will be no time indicator, so the event might just happened or happened yesterday, and then passive voice will be for:

- present simple : she is hurt
- past simple : she was hurt

Comment: *Always* does not imply present tense; we say, for instance, "When I was a kid we always went to the Sea Islands in the summer." And I think you have a typo: "she is always **her**".

Comment: um very grateful...dude..done ur best...